# How to execute this mysql query in VB.NET10 which contains := operator in it

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have this SQL statement:

```
CREATE TABLE D1 AS (
    SELECT 
        q1.ID,q1.ItemName, q1.Purchase, q1.Sale,
        CASE 
            WHEN @itemname:=q1.ItemName THEN 
                @runtot := @runtot + (q1.Purchase + q1.Sale) 
            ELSE @runtot:=(q1.Purchase + q1.Sale)End AS ClosingBalance,          
        @itemname := q1.ItemName as Item 
    FROM 
        (SELECT 
             ID AS ID, ItemName AS ItemName, 
             Purchase AS Purchase, Sale AS Sale
         FROM 
             itemledger 
         ORDER BY
             ItemName) AS q1)
```

In command line this query works perfectly. When I put it in VB.NET code its not working.

```vb
Dim query922 = "CREATE TABLE D1 AS (SELECT q1.ID,q1.ItemName,q1.Purchase,q1.Sale, CASE WHEN @itemname=q1.ItemName THEN @runtot := @runtot + (q1.Purchase + q1.Sale) ELSE @runtot:=(q1.Purchase + q1.Sale)End AS ClosingBalance, @itemname:=q1.ItemName as Item FROM (SELECT ID AS ID,ItemName AS ItemName,Purchase AS Purchase,Sale AS Sale  FROM  itemledger ORDER  BY ItemName) AS q1) "
On Error Resume Next
Using connection922 As New MySqlConnection(connectionString922)
    Dim command922 As New MySqlCommand(query922, connection922)

    command922.Connection.Open()
    command922.ExecuteScalar()
    command922.Connection.Close()
End Using
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':= 0 + (q1.Purchase + q1.Sale) ELSE 0:=(q1.Purchase + q1.Sale)End AS ClosingBala' at line 1

I tried this, too:

```vb
Dim query922 = "CREATE TABLE D1 AS (SELECT q1.ID,q1.ItemName,q1.Purchase,q1.Sale, CASE WHEN @itemname=q1.ItemName THEN @runtot := @runtot + (q1.Purchase + q1.Sale) ELSE @runtot:=(q1.Purchase + q1.Sale)End AS ClosingBalance, @itemname:=q1.ItemName as Item FROM (SELECT ID AS ID,ItemName AS ItemName,Purchase AS Purchase,Sale AS Sale  FROM  itemledger ORDER  BY ItemName) AS q1) "
On Error Resume Next
Using connection922 As New MySqlConnection(connectionString922)
    Dim command922 As New MySqlCommand(query922, connection922)

    command922.Parameters.AddWithValue("@runtot", 0)
    command922.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemname", "NULL")
    command922.Connection.Open()
    command922.ExecuteScalar()
    command922.Connection.Close()
End Using
```

Comment: *"its not working"* is never an adequate description of a problem.  Show us the actual VB code you're using to execute the SQL and explain what actually does happen when you execute it.

Comment: Please check and let me know.

Comment: Just a guess with no error to go on, but you need to create query parameters for `@itemname` and `@runtot`

Comment: Okay, update to the question as I was typing the comment shows parameters. `NULL` is still wrong, though. It needs to be `DBNull.Value` instead. But we still need to see the error, and that can't happen until you remove `On Error Resume Next`, which is really only still part of the language for backwards compatibility with old vb6-era code and should no longer be used for new development.

Comment: OK i changed to DBNull.Value still not working

Comment: Oh ok "On Error Resume Next" removed

Comment: It shows this "...You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':= 0 + (q1.Purchase + q1.Sale) ELSE 0:=(q1.Purchase + q1.Sale)End AS ClosingBala' at line 1..."

Comment: First, remove `command922.ExecuteScalar()` and do `command922.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Comment: Changed to command922.ExecuteNonQuery() still showing same error msg.

Comment: And, aren't you supposed to do `SET @itemname = X; CREATE...`?

Comment: In that last code snippet, you have replace the first `:=` with `=` but you left all the others.  If you replace them all, does it work as expected?

Comment: BY doing so, it showing another error msg "fatal error"

Comment: jmcilhinney - no its not working. If replace ":=" with "=" then calculation not happening.It returning 0.

Comment: (And, aren't you supposed to do SET @itemname = X; CREATE...? – T.S).............BY doing so, it showing another error msg "fatal error"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ":=" operator wont work in Visual Studio 10 which supports till .net 4 version, given code requires higher version of .net framework....